# Docusign Integration - Single integration key for multi-tenant application

Tags: integration, docusignapi

We're trying to implement a Docusign integration for a multi-tenant cloud application (i.e. https://company1.app.com, https://company2.app.com, etc...).

The goal is to allow the tenant admin (our customer) to upload envelopes containing document templates for users to sign when they first login.   Each tenant admin will have their own Docusign account/envelopes.

We've implemented a solution for this; however, it requires each tenant admin to create a separate Integration key and go through the process of promoting it to a live account.  This is not scalable for us and some of our tenant admins are not tech people, so they have trouble setting this up.

Is there a way to implement the Docusign integration using a single Integration key (our key), but still have tenant admins login with their own Docusign account and upload their own envelopes?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are building a Docusign [User Application](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/api-overview#common-user).  You should use the [OAuth2](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/auth_server.html) auth flows instead of creating separate Integrator key for each tentant.

> A **user application** is a client that authenticates every end user with DocuSign. These applications are typically web services, mobile applications, or desktop programs that authenticate individual users on the DocuSign platform. Once authenticated, users give consent for the application to display, send, or sign envelopes from their account. For user applications the OAuth2 auth flows are recommended.

Comment: Thanks CodingDawg!  I mentioned this to the development team as well; however, they were under the impression that clients wouldn't be able to use Docusign envelopes and templates if we went down this path.  Do you know if this is the case?

Comment: using the oAuth2 auth flow your app should be able to access the envelopes and templates of user. As part of the authentication process, users give consent for your application to display, send, or sign envelopes from their account.

Comment: Here will DocuSign charge the application for creating integrator key for the app and creating envelopes on behalf of tenants? How is it working? Or only customers will be paid based on their usage/package?

Answer (score 0):

A key issue that you may be missing is that your Integration Key works with any account. It is associated with your account just to manage it.

So as CodingDawg says, each of your customers can use your app by logging in with their own user credentials for their own account.