# DocuSign Integration / API

Tags: docusignapi

Task is to implement a DocuSign integration for numerous tenants.

We have found a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42823344/docusign-integration-single-integration-key-for-multi-tenant-application) giving us a hint how to do it.

But there are more questions:

1. what subscription would be good to implement the integration?
2. if we connect to the tenant's account using a master key(belongs to the integrator, not to the tenant), and create envelopes in the tenant's account, who pays then - the integrator or the tenant in whose account the envelope is created?

Answer (score 0):

*Q: what subscription would be good to implement the integration?*

DocuSign offers various [api plans](https://secure.docusign.com/developer). Your tenants will have to choose the appropriate plan depending on their feature set and transaction requirements.

*Q: Who pays - the integrator or the tenant?*

The tenant will need to purchase a paid DocuSign account to create and send envelopes through your integration.

Comment: Q: Who pays - the integrator or the tenant?

The tenant will need to purchase a paid DocuSign account to create and send envelopes through your integration.
This is common knowledge and the question was not about this.

Comment: The tenant pays.